# Python Pandas: Resample date range

Tags: python, pandas

I create a list of pandas datetimes with the following line:

```
range = pd.date_range(start = '5/3/2005', periods =5+1, freq='1D')
```

Is there a quick way to resample that list so that it spans the same range but with a frequency of 30 min? (so far I can only see applications of that logic to Series or DataFrames index, but no daterange)

Comment: `range.to_series().asfreq('30 min').index`? Also, `range` is a builtin function, so I would not call the variable "range".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start = '5/3/2005', periods =5+1, freq='1D')
new_date_range = pd.date_range(date_range.min(), date_range.max(), freq='30 min')
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start = '5/3/2005', periods =5+1, freq='1D')
new_date_range = date_range.to_series().asfreq('30 min').index
```

Also, `range` is a builtin function, so I would not call the variable "range".

I hope this helps.

Comment: @piRSquared  So resampling function in python/pandas only exist for Series/ DataFrames? I was aware of that, but as mentionned in my question was wondering if there would be a similar function performing on lists

Comment: @jimbasquiat that "list" is actually a `DatetimeIndex`.  It being a `DatetimeIndex` is what enables Abdou to do what they did.  `asfreq()` is a convenient way to `resample`.  It operates on the index of a `Series` or `DataFrame`.  However, you need a `Series` to do it.  I'll post an alternative, though I still think this is more elegant.